# What is the difference between generic and branded flashtoolfirmwarefiles (.ftf)?

Tags: rooting, device-firmware, downgrade, flashtool, sony-xperia-z1

I want to root my phone a **Sony Xperia Z1 C6903** and followed [this guide](http://techbeasts.com/how-to-update-sony-xperia-z1-c6903-to-official-android-4-4-4-kitkat-14-4-a-0-108-firmware/) to downgrade it to **Android 4.4.4 KitKat 14.4.A.0.108** Firmware first.

Because the link to the provided firmware is dead I searched for an equivalent one and found [this directory](http://storagecow.eu/index.php?dir=Xda%2FSony%2FXperia+Z1%2FC6903%2F).

Now there are few more .ftf's for *14.4.A.0.108* firmware so which one should I select?

What is the difference between generic and branded firmware?

What are the differences between the different generic .ftf's and the different branded .ftf's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. What is a generic firmware?

A generic firmware is the firmware for an android device published by the devices manufacturer.

### 2. What is a branded firmware?

A branded firmware is a firmware customized by cell phone providers to advertise themself by showing their logo, installing apps or adding bookmarks to the browser. Updates for branded phones getting released later then for generic phones, because the provider has to customize the new updates first. This is the reason why it is always better to have a generic firmware.

### 3. What is the difference between generic and branded firmware?

The difference depents on the changes a cell phone provider accomplishes.

### 4. What are the differences between the different generic .ftf's and the different branded .ftf's?

The difference between several branded .ftf's of the same *Build Number* depending on the changes a cell phone provider accomplishes.

The difference between several generic .ftf's of the same *Build Number* depending on customization the user of this firmware accomplishes before uploading it on the internet. In most cases this recognizable by the keyword *customized* in the name of the .ftf.

### 5. Now there are few more .ftf's for a specific *Build Number* so which one should I select?

In most cases the differences are minimal so it is more or less arbitrary which one to choose BUT there are several helpful indicators to choose a .ftf which fits the most:

- Always choose a generic .ftf.
- Choose region and country nearest to the phones residence.
- If the .ftf is from a forum check user posts for issues.

Comment: Is is a big deal if say I were to install a Ukraine generic on a phone from the UK?

Comment: @tupto Why should it if its for the same mobile phone? So no...